# Cypress nyc code coverage is not instrumenting the code

Tags: code-coverage, cypress, nyc

I am trying to introduce e2e code coverage in my react app. I can see `hash-file.json` is getting created in `.nyc_output`

below are my `package.json` scripts

```
{
        "start": "npm run clean && cross-env NODE_ENV=test node ./tools/devServer.js",
        "e2e": "nyc cypress open",
}
```

[image]

its not updating `.nyc_output/out.json`

[image]

```
.babelrc

{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-react"
    ],
    "env": {
        "test": {
          "plugins": [ "istanbul"], {
            "exclude": [
              "src/**/*.spec.js",
              "src/**/*.test.js",
              "e2e-coverage"
            ],
            "include":["src/"]
          }]
        }
      },
    "ignore": ["node_modules","build"]
}
```

1. What are the above has-file.json, and why it gets created, if i followed correctly instead of this it should write the coverage in out.json ?
2. I followed the [document](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/code-coverage.html#Instrumenting-code), but still it looks like there is some issue in instrumenting the code. (what could be the issue ?)
3. In some of the examples i saw logs with `isInteractive:true`, what is this meant for and where is its configuration handler ?
4. What could be the expected cause for it not getting instrumented
   [image]

[image]

**Solution:-**

I followed and included the instrumenting process as part of webpack build loader, and it's working fine. But still i am looking answers for by above points.
I was expecting `babel-istanbul-plugin` will do it on the fly, no need to do with webpack.

https://webpack.js.org/loaders/istanbul-instrumenter-loader/

Comment: @RichardMatsen No here i am not using CRA.

Comment: @RichardMatsen updated the question with .babelrc and start script

Comment: There's a few possibilities, do you have a repo to look at?

Comment: See [here](https://github.com/cypress-io/code-coverage/blob/ad8deffb4af78429bd67b4a50857276253f91890/task.js#L91) for `isInteractive` flag, it's to cope with different ways of running tests in Cypress.

Comment: yes, i reached there, and if you see i am using cypress open, but its keeping it as isInteractive as undefined  and not logging it in cy run console.

Comment: Your screen shot shows it is `isInteractive:true`, not `undefined`. Reading the comments in the source code, you can see this flag is to control the clear-down between tests not the logging.